# Open only div what i want(jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, css, modal-dialog, display

Title is maybe misleading, but i try you explain it.
[My table of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg84J.png)
and When i click on the cross I want open only div with `id` for example as `#` in table(id=1, id=2...)

So here is my php code:

```
$select = "SELECT ... from ...";
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $select);
$count = 0;
echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>";
while ($query = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
            $counter++;
            echo "<tr>
            <th>{$counter}</th>
            <td>{$query["name"]}</td>
            <td><a href='xxx.php?id={$query["id"]}'><i class='ion-edit'></i></a><i class='ion-close-round'></i>
<div class='modal'> //modal have of course display none!
  <div class='mContent'>
    <div class='mHeader'>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='mMiddle'>
      <a href='xxx.php?id={$query['id']}'>delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Jquery:

```
$('.ion-close-round').on('click', function () {
 $('.modal').css("display", "block");
});
```

this script "open" every modal of course, but i want open only modal with given id

Thanks for your help all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.next()` to target the `.modal` that comes after `.ion-close-round`

```
$('.ion-close-round').on('click', function () {
 $(this).next('.modal').css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: Oh nice man, I really love you :D it works Thank you soooo much

Comment: @Dolis no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

The selector . is a class selector.

You want to use the ID selector which is #

The ID selector is stricter as only one element on an HTML page can have a given ID, so your ID is 'modal', it would only work on the first element with the ID of modal.

Comment: yes i know it work only for first modal but do you have some solution ? thank you